# how to get hystrix circuit state?

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix

I'm developing a Spring Boot application with Hystrix for a circuit breaker.

In my application, one business flow consists of several network call to different microservices (e.g. get some data from service A, then based on the response, call service B and C, and based on the response from B and C, call service D).

I need to block the entire flow if **any** of the services are down.

Does anyone know when a circuit is open or closed or half-open?

Answer (score 2):

It feels a bit hacky, but there are some static methods that can get you access to Hystrix's wrapped commands, which in turn gives you access to circuit-status:

```java
HystrixCircuitBreaker myCircuitBreaker = HystrixCircuitBreaker.Factory.getInstance(HystrixCommandKey.Factory.asKey("my command name"))
if(myCircuitBreaker.isOpen()) {
   ...proceed
}
```